# Hide downgrade option of Jenkins CI Server

Tags: jenkins

The **Manage Jenkins** page shows a `div` with a *caption* and a *button* that offers to downgrade to the lastly installed version, as shown on the picture. Here is a screenshot showing the respective part highlighted in red.

[image: Partial screenshot of the caption and the downgrade button]

I checked the HTML and I could manipulate the CSS `.downgrade` class  to hide the `<div>`, but maybe I am missing out a configuration option.

Does Jenkins offer a way to disable or hide the possibility to downgrade?

Comment: Do you just want to hide the downgrade option or do you want to remove it?

Comment: Removing would be preferable, but hiding would do the job, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove the downgrade button you need to remove or rename the `jenkins.war` backup file in the Jenkins installation folder. For example in the case of my Jenkins installation (1.625.3) the UI shows:

[image: Jenkins management page with downgrade option]

And (part of) the Jenkins installation folder looks like this:

[image: Jenkins installation folder before renaming backup]

Note that the folder has a `jenkins.war.bak` file. If you rename this file to anything else Jenkins will assume that there is no older version to downgrade to so it will not display the downgrade button. 
In other words if I rename `jenkins.war.bak` to `jenkins.war.bak.old` like this:

[image: Jenkins installation folder after renaming backup]

Then the management UI page will look like this:

[image: Jenkins management page without downgrade option]

Which accomplishes the goal you were after.